# How to differentiate multiple window instances of Cmder?

Tags: conemu, cmder

Good day!

I'm having a difficult time determining which window instance of Cmder I need when I'm doing `Alt+Tab` in window. All of my Cmder instances are just named `[1/1] Cmder`. Is there a way to customize this name? I've been looking at the settings but it seems there is no configuration for it. Either that or I'm just dumb so I'm taking my chances here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's default cmder settings.

In ConEmu the defaults are that your window title is the title of your console. So you can easily differentiate them, as the title usually shows your current condone directory (cmd, PowerShell, Far, etc.)

Optionally you may run ConEmu with `-title` switch. For example `ConEmu64.exe -title "My cool project"`.

- https://conemu.github.io/en/ConEmuArgs.html
- https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsTabBar.html

Comment: Cmder is running ConEmu under the hood right @Maximus? so I need to run Cmder with those parameters? Is that what you are saying? Or is your answer solely for ConEmu?

Comment: Cmder is a bundle, bootstrapper. I see no need to run cmder at all. It's just a configuration.

Comment: Thank you @Maximus! I did not know I can invoke ConEmu and it will still follow the Cmder config. Thanks a lot!